# map.where returning NA

Tags: r, maps

Why isn't map.where finding the right county for this GPS coordinate?

```
> maps::map.where('county', y =  47.9078 , x = -122.2803)
[1] NA
```

It works for other points in Washington.

```
> maps::map.where('county',  y = 46.0900, x = -121.7600)
[1] "washington,skamania"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you look in detail, you will see the point in fact falls just outside all polygons:

```
> maps::map('county',xlim=c(-123,-122),ylim=c(47,48),fill=TRUE)
> points( y =  47.9078 , x = -122.2803,col=2)
```

[image]
So the NA result is normal in that respect. It may of course be wrong due to the limited resolution of the county map. Clearly the point is very close to or on the coast, and maybe a better quality map may give a different result. Using `rnaturalearth` you can make a similar plot, which clearly shows the difference:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
cc=ne_states(iso_a2="US")
maps::map(cc,xlim=c(-123,-122),ylim=c(47,48),fill=TRUE)
points( y =  47.9078 , x = -122.2803,col=2)
maps::map('county',xlim=c(-123,-122),ylim=c(47,48),add=TRUE,col=3)
```

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Has this issue ever been raised with the package author(s) I wonder? I can imagine many instances where coastal coordinates are not mapped to a country as a result of this issue.

Comment: Well, actually, I /am/ the maintainer (though not the original author) of the maps package. So yes, I am aware. I have added the possibility of using other, higher resolution maps. But it can not really be considered a bug in the code. Finding the closest polygon could be an option, of course, but it should never be default behaviour. Note that the same problem could arrise with points close to internal borders. There you could just get a wrong country if the map resolution is insufficient. I have added a clear warning for this.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Indeed, the `map.where` function works perfectly fine and I was not suggesting at all that this issue was a bug. The higher resolution map fix is a good option and just knowing that this can occur at boundaries informs the analyst. Thanks again.